# From last 15 days Not able to Login with sandbox Credentials for Test In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I tried lot of time to create new sandbox IAP Account but always give error message. Please check attachment. [image]

I am facing this issue from last 15 days. before 15-20 days ago its working fine even apple does not ask me validate sandbox account ID. it will be work fine without any validation. but now I am not able to login in my app for testing IAP.

Comment: create new one and try and see.

Comment: I tried  and create more then 15 times but got the  same issue. May be Apple have changed the policy. Because now I need to verify the sandbox accounts also , but previously it work without any verification.

Comment: This appears to be an issue at the moment. I have seen a number of similar questions asked here. I suggest you log a support case with Apple. By the way, guaranteed is misspelt and I am not sure that you should make that statement since you do not have the ability to refund in app purchases

Comment: It's true that they currently have a problem such that you cannot test an in-app purchase.  But it has not been 15 days.  I was able to test it in Dec. 30th or 31st of last year.